# How do I write a query in SQL with an exclusive?

Tags: postgresql

Using the SELECT COUNT and BETWEEN operators I also need to exclude two integers.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 50
```

I need to exclude 20 and 30.  I’ve tried using NOT, NOT IN and NULL.  What am I missing?

Comment: That’s exactly right.  All the examples I viewed online weren’t helpful.  Thank you a_horse_with_no_name.  I’ve just started a boot camp and I’ve never used SQL before.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 50
  AND user_id NOT IN (20,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "AND  user_id NOT IN (20,30)" doesn't work?  Could try just adding a "user_id <> 20 AND user_id <> 30"